# Server returned http response code 407 for url: "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.7.dtd

Tags: struts2

I am new to Struts2. I was trying to execute a simple Struts2 program.
Apparently my `struts.xml` is not invoking the action.

It shows a warning `Server returned http response code 407 for url: "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.7.dtd` in my `struts.xml`.

`struts.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.7.dtd">

 <struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="hello" class="com.FirstStruts.ExampleStruts" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/Helloworld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>

 </struts>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`Action:`

```
package com.FirstStruts;

public class ExampleStruts {
    private String f_name;
    private String l_name;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello. in execeute");
        return "success";   
    }

    public String getF_name() {
        return f_name;
    }

    public void setF_name(String f_name) {
        this.f_name = f_name;
    }

    public String getL_name() {
        return l_name;
    }

    public void setL_name(String l_name) {
        this.l_name = l_name;
    }


}
```

When I try to execute, I am getting the error `There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name ExampleStruts.`

I am using the jars mentioned in http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/struts2/basic-struts2-project-setup

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: With what url are you trying to access your action?

Comment: I'm executing it on internal browser. It's, http://localhost:8080/exampleStruts/index.jsp would you want me to put index.jsp here??

Comment: Why do you access JSP directly? Use actions.

Answer (score 1):

Your action is called `hello`, no `ExampleStruts`, so it won't find it. Change your `struts.xml` file:

```
<action name="ExampleStruts" class="com.FirstStruts.ExampleStruts">
    <result>/Helloworld.jsp</result>
</action>
```

or invoke the action correctly in your `index.jsp`.

Also, you need to extend your action from `ActionSupport`, so it will be recognized as an action.

Comment: I thought it's optional. Isn't it? anyways is my dtd correct? it still shows a warning there.

Comment: @Reddy_73 Can you be more specific about the error? And I don't think the dtd is what is giving you problems.

Comment: @Reddy_73: So your action is working and you get just warning about dtd?

Comment: No, action is not getting invoked at all. I was wondering if it's related to that warning. please let me know if you need any of the details.

Comment: @Armaggedon I have given every detail about the error. let me knoww if want to know any other details. Thanks

Comment: @Reddy_73 Are you still getting `There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name ExampleStruts` error? Did you change `struts.xml` file and redeployed the application?

Comment: @Armaggedon yes I did and I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Reddy_73 Did you try to specify a correct schema version in the `web.xml`, also in `struts.xml` you should specify the `dtd` that corresponds to your `struts2-core-x.x.x.jar`. You could extract the latest from this jar and point to the url.

Comment: @Armaggedon Not sure about schema version but I am using proper version of dtd i suppose, as i picked it from http://struts.apache.org/dtds/ and using the relevant one(no 2.2.* is there so using 2.1.7)